# Parse / split many columns to multiple columns in pandas dataframe using custom function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, split

I've consulted a bunch of previous related SO posts, but I could not adapt them to solve my question.

Here is an example dataframe.

```py
# Using pandas 0.24.2
data = {'customer_id': [1, 2, 3],
        'prev_due_date':['Jun-2010', 'Apr-2019', 'Dec-1999'], 
        'current_due_date':['Aug-2019', 'Dec-2045', 'Jan-2000'],
        'next_due_date':['Feb-2025', 'Nov-2065', 'Sep-2001']
       } 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Here is what the dataframe looks like, and there are many more such columns to parse in actual dataframe, hence my question.

```py
    customer_id prev_due_date   current_due_date    next_due_date
0   1           Jun-2010        Aug-2019            Feb-2025
1   2           Apr-2019        Dec-2045            Nov-2065
2   3           Dec-1999        Jan-2000            Sep-2001
```

I have created a function to parse one column (ie, this adds two parsed columns --- month and year columns --- to the supplied df)

```py
def parse_column(df, col_parse):

    col_parse_mmm = col_parse + '_mmm'
    col_parse_yyyy = col_parse + '_yyyy'

    df[[col_parse_mmm, col_parse_yyyy]] = df[col_parse].str.split('-', expand=True)

    return df
```

Calling this function below does the job for the supplied column:

```py
parse_column(df, 'prev_due_date')
```

Now, my question is:

1. How can I do this for an arbitrary number columns of my choosing (eg, list of of tens or hundreds columns that I want to parse), using ***apply***?
2. Is it possible to avoid using ***apply***?

Comment: I guess the main question is why do you need to do this? If it's so that you can manipulate the dates, there are better ways to store this information without replicating the data across hundreds of columns.

Comment: Why don't you just use `pd.to_datetime` in your columns, and whenever you need the `month`, you use the .dt.month` acessor?

Comment: @ALollz My choice of date columns in my example may be misleading. I actually want to parse an arbitrary number of character columns, like full address with city and zip, but I happened to pick date columns in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for c in df.columns:
    if c.endswith('_date'):
        parse_column(df, c)
```

(you don't need return the df in your parse_column function)

If you already have the list with the column names you're interested in:

```
for c in my_columns_list:
    parse_column(df, c)
```

You don't need any `apply`.

Comment: when you state "you don't need return the df in your parse_column function", what do you mean? if my parse_column function does not return df with two named parsed columns, do you mean to return the generic "0" and "1" columns?

Comment: You don't need to return anything. Arguments are passed by assignement. When you call your function `parse_column(df, c)`, you create a reference to `df` and pass this reference by value to the function. You can convince yourself of it but putting a `print(id(df))` before, inside and after the function: all ids will be identical. See also [item #3 here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference).